# How can I use Javascript to display text from another web page onto a different page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website, lets call it abc.com. I need to automatically retrieve text from another page called static.abc.com/pluginchangelog.txt and display the text at the top of that page on abc.com/plugin.

I'm new to Javascript. I've searched and searched, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer. I found this page, [Javascript access another webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315235/javascript-access-another-webpage), but I'm not sure how to implement this for the use that I need. Even if I could figure that part out, I don't know how to insert that text into the HTML of the page.

I would appreciate any guidance!

Comment: use localStorage?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: @brk How would I implement this if everything is being hosted on aws?

Answer (score 2):

Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get text

Then edit content on your page how you want

```js
fetch("https://example.com/pluginchangelog.txt", {credentials: "omit"}).then(resp => resp.text()).then(text => {
  // do anything you want with text
  content.innerText = text
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @hindmost added `{credentials: "omit"}`

Comment: I meant [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue. `credentials` option has no relation to CORS, it's about cookies.

Comment: BTW, the OP referenced AJAX-related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315235/javascript-access-another-webpage) in his question. It's similar to yours except that post is a bit outdated now.

Comment: Does this bypass the same-origin policy?